# Multi configuration Jenkins job

Tags: curl, jenkins

I have a `multi configuration matrix job` that consists of 3 configurations.  I have one user defined axis lets call it ParameterA and it has 3 values value1, value2, value3 for each configuration.

The job also has a promote process.  In the promote process I copy the 3 artifacts produced and I'd like to use groovy/curl to push them to Artifactory.

In order to do this I need to loop through the names of the artifacts (the names are made up of the jobName-.

Is there a way to retrieve or save all the values of ParameterA so that I can loop through them and perform a curl command to upload each one?

Something like `ParameterA=value1,value2,value3`

Answer (score 0):

One way you could do this is by using the [Groovy Postbuild Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Groovy+Postbuild+Plugin) in the promote process job (I'm assuming it's a separate job?).

In the postbuild step, you will have access to the [Jenkins model](http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/index.html?hudson/model/Hudson.html) which contains everything you would probably need to extract the ParameterA axis, as well as the ability to upload via groovy/curl.

Unfortunately, I can't get to the Jenkins javadoc right now, so I couldn't look up the necessary functions to retrieve the corresponding ParameterA axis, but hopefully this will get you started.